# Select another attribute if the original attribute is NULL (Conditional select)

Tags: sql, select, null, oracle10g

How can i achieve if i want to select an attribute ONLY and ONLY if another attribute is NULL.

I know the long way of this:

```
select val1 from test_table where val1 is not null
OR
select val2 from test_table where val1 is null
```

The bad with this solution that if i have a very long and complicated select then i need to write it twice...

EG:

```
select val1 from test_table where condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 AND val1 is not null
OR
select val2 from test_table where condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 AND val1 is null
```

So i hope, maybe there is a shorter form for this. Anyway this is something like an IF or CASE in programming languages (i think).

Any idea appreciated.
First ide: inside select can shorten the second select

Comment: What database system? Different systems use different function names for this: isnull vs if vs coalesce vs ifnull etc

Comment: Oracle 10g, but it would be good if the solution would be general. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select coalesce(val1, val2) from test_table
```

Comment: Can i use something similar in a join? I mean select * from  test_table1 t1 inner join test_table2 on coalesce(t1.name,t1.id)=t2.id

Comment: thanks i've already tried it. Accepted you, thanks again, appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ISNULL(val1,val2)
FROM test_table
```

Or

```
SELECT COALESCE(val1,val2)
FROM test_table
```

I prefer the latter because you can have multiple values like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(val1,val2,val3,val4,....,valn)
FROM test_table
```

which means if val1 is null then take val2, if that is null too then take val3 etc until it gets to valn...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `case` expression as below

```
select 
  case 
    when condition1 is not null AND condition2 is not null AND condition3 is not null AND val1 is not null then val1
    when condition1 is null     AND condition2 is null     AND condition3 is null     AND val1 is null     then val2
    else null
  end
from test_table
```